# Fill data gaps - UNION, PARTITION BY, or JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Problem**

There are data gaps that need to be filled. Would like to avoid `UNION` or `PARTITION BY` if possible.

**Query Statement**

The select statement reads as follows:

```
SELECT
  count( r.incident_id ) AS incident_tally,
  r.severity_cd,
  r.incident_typ_cd
FROM
  report_vw r
GROUP BY
  r.severity_cd, r.incident_typ_cd
ORDER BY
  r.severity_cd,
  r.incident_typ_cd
```

**Data Sources**

The severity codes and incident type codes are from:

- `severity_vw`
- `incident_type_vw`

The columns are:

- incident_tally
- severity_cd
- incident_typ_cd

**Actual Result Data**

```
36  0   ENVIRONMENT
1   1   DISASTER
27  1   ENVIRONMENT
4   2   SAFETY
1   3   SAFETY
```

**Required Result Data**

```
36  0   ENVIRONMENT
0   0   DISASTER
0   0   SAFETY
27  1   ENVIRONMENT
0   1   DISASTER
0   1   SAFETY
0   2   ENVIRONMENT
0   2   DISASTER
4   2   SAFETY
0   3   ENVIRONMENT
0   3   DISASTER
1   3   SAFETY
```

**Question**

How would you use `UNION`, `PARTITION BY`, or `LEFT JOIN` to fill in the zero counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(r.incident_id),
        crsjn.severity_cd,
        crsjn.incident_typ_cd
FROM    (
            SELECT  severity_cd,
                    incident_typ_cd
            FROM    severity_vw,
                    incident_type_vw
        ) crsjn LEFT JOIN
        report_vw r     ON  crsjn.severity_cd = r.severity_cd 
                        AND crsjn.incident_typ_cd = r.incident_typ_cd
GROUP BY crsjn.severity_cd,
        crsjn.incident_typ_cd
ORDER BY crsjn.severity_cd,
        crsjn.incident_typ_cd
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be if you had incident type and incident severity in another table.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sub.incident_tally), s.severity_cd, i.incident_type_cd
FROM incident_type i
CROSS JOIN incident_severity s
LEFT JOIN (
   ... your original sql statement...
) sub ON i.incident_typ_cd = sub.incident_type_cd
  AND s.severity_cd = sub.severity_cd
```

And if you didn't have those tables, you could do something like this. I don't understand why the no UNION restriction. But this works.

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
CREATE TYPE NUMBER_TABLE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

WITH inc AS (
  SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(nt1 3) */ column_value AS incident_type_cd
  FROM TABLE(varchar_table('ENVIRONMENT', 'DISASTER', 'SAFETY')) nt1
),
sev AS (
  SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(nt2 4) */ column_value AS severity_cd
  FROM TABLE(number_table(0,1,2,3)) nt2
) 
SELECT *
FROM inc
CROSS JOIN sev
LEFT JOIN (
   ... your original sql statement...
) sub ON i.incident_typ_cd = sub.incident_type_cd
  AND s.severity_cd = sub.severity_cd
```

4

Comment: For this solution, you should use the cardinality hint on the nested tables.  Otherwise, the optimizer will assume those tables are each the size of a block.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Allan. I added the hints to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is to further normalise that table and use a left join.

Comment: It's not a table. It's a view on data coming from several tables. And normalization is no longer possible -- the project has gone into sustainment; only bug fixes and minor updates are allowed.

Comment: Then i suggest to get the entire list of severities and incidents from a table and then join this view with a left join.